# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made a get request but I have an error about _id param it can not be read

app.get('/users/:id', (res, req) => {
const _id = req.params.id

```
    if(_id.length != 24) {
        res.status(404).send(`id length must be do not less than 24 digit`)
    } else {
        User.findById(_id).then((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).send(`the user id is not found `)
            }
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }).catch((e) => {
            res.status(500).send(e)
    })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
User.findById({_id:_id})
Tell me if it works

Comment: still same error

Comment: Can you send the whole code please

Comment: ` 
app.get('/users/:id', (res, req) => {
    const id = req.params.id
        if(id.length != 24) {
            res.status(404).send(`id length should be 24 digit`)
        } else {
            User.findById({ _id:id }).then((user) => {
                if (!user) {
                     res.status(404).send(`the user id is not found `)
                }
                res.status(200).send(user)
            }).catch((e) => {
                res.status(500).send(e)
        })
        }
    }) `

Comment: Can you show your request? Example: http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/users/YOUR_USER_ID

Comment: localhost:3000/users/12345678

Comment: Did you write that id by yourself, or copied it from a user id? Because 12345678 looks like an selfmade id

Comment: localhost:3000/users/6277a838057fae2f632a1f71

Comment: this is another request with existence id already with the same error response

Answer (score 0):

```
const id = req.params.id;
if(id.length != 24) {
        res.status(404).send(`id length sholud be 24 digit`)
    } else {
        User.findById({_id:id}).then((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).send(`the user id is not found `)
            }
            res.status(200).send(user)
        }).catch((e) => {
            res.status(500).send(e)
    })
    }
})
```

Comment: app.get('/users/:id', (res, req) => {
    const id = req.params.id
        if(id.length != 24) {
            res.status(404).send(`id length should be 24 digit`)
        } else {
            User.findById({ _id:id }).then((user) => {
                if (!user) {
                    return res.status(404).send(`the user id is not found `)
                }
                res.status(200).send(user)
            }).catch((e) => {
                res.status(500).send(e)
        })
        }
    })

still same error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: I have been try this it doesn't work

Comment: please send us the whle code it could help

Answer (score 0):

finally, I get it. it's about id in mongoose must transform it to string and then length must be equal to 12 bytes.

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req,res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id
  if(_id.toString().length!= 12) {
    User.findById(_id).then((user) => 
      if(!user) {
         return res.status(404).send('unable to find user')
      }
      return res.status(200).send(user)
    }).catch((e) => {
      return res.status(500).send(e)
    })
  } else {
    res.status(400).send('bad objectID')
  }
})
```